# Abrir o GridView2 selecionando um campo GridView1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Olá. 
Estou tentando fazer com que toda vez que eu selecione um campo específico dentro do **GridView1**, ele abra dados relacionados em um Banco de Dados Access no **GridView2**. 
Esse é o código da minha página.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" CodeBehind="MainView.aspx.vb" Inherits="DosimetryASPNET_WebApplication.MainView" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnMenuView" runat="server" Text="Return to Menu" Width="200px" OnClick="btnMenuView_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="server">
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BatchID" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchID" HeaderText="BatchID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BatchID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="Product" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchSize" HeaderText="BatchSize" SortExpression="BatchSize" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="Priority" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartReq" HeaderText="StartReq" SortExpression="StartReq" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString1 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [AllBatches]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BatchID" Visible="False">
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

Esse é o código que utilizo para popular o GridView1

```
Private Sub GridView1_LoadData(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim dt As New Northwind.AllBatchesDataTable
        Using da As New NorthwindTableAdapters.AllBatchesTableAdapter
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
            GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
            GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Estou utilizando um banco de dados **Access** e para popular o **GridView2** utilizo uma segunda tabela.

Para o **GridView1** utilizo a tabela "**AllBatches**" com as seguintes colunas:
**BatchID** - **Product** - **BatchSize** - **Priority** - **StartReq** - **Status**

Para o **GridView2** quero que a tabela "**IngredientsTable**" seja chamada. Ela contém as seguintes colunas:
**LotManufactID** - **Ingredient** - **Actual** - **Target** - **Minimum** - **Maximum** - **WeighinhDate** - **Status** - **IDBatchID**

No meu banco **Access**, a tabela funciona como eu gostaria que funcionasse em ASP.NET.
Quando clico no "**BatchID**" do "**AllBatches**" ele abre uma tabela secundária na linha abaixo da linha que cliquei com os dados do "**IngredientsTable**".
Eu criei uma relação no banco entre as duas tabelas.

Talvez fique muito complexo para fazer dessa forma, mas preciso de ajuda para desenvolver essa funcionalidade que pelo menos abra no  **GridView2** os dados da "**IngredientsTable**" que tenham relação com o "**BatchID**" da "**AllBatches**".

Espero que tenha conseguido exemplificar minha dúvida e ser claro.
Aguardo por ajuda.